# python bound method Error

Tags: python

I have a problem about python 2.7 and the def functions in a class as there're problems about bound method. And this is an assignment from school :D

## Here's the code :

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import math

```
class Shapes(object):
    __metaclass__= ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class TwoDShapes(Shapes):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class ThreeDShapes(Shapes):
def __init__(self):
        pass
================= Main.py =====================
from BasicClassShapes import*

class Rectangle(TwoDShapes):
    def __init__(self, nameOfShape, length, width, numberofSides, numberOfVertices):
        self.nameOfShape = "Rectangle"
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.numberofSides = 4
        self.numberOfVertices = 4
        super(Rectangle,self).__init__()

    def perimeter(self):
        self.perimeter = length*2 + width*2
    def Area(self):
        self.Area = length*width

====================================

def PrintALL():

    A = Rectangle("Rectangle", "10", "20", "4",  "4")

    print "This is the name of the shape: ", A.nameOfShape
    print "This is the length: ", A.length
    print "This is the width: ", A.width
    print "This is the number of side: ", A.numberofSides
    print "This is the number of vertice: ", A.numberOfVertices
    print "This is the perimeter: ", A.perimeter
    print "This is the area: ", A.Area
    print "\n"
PrintALL()


=============== Result =======================
This is the name of the shape:  Rectangle
This is the length:  10
This is the width:  20
This is the number of side:  4
This is the number of vertice:  4
This is the perimeter:  <bound method Rectangle.perimeter of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x03BEFC90>>

This is the area:  `<bound method Rectangle.Area of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x03BEFC90>>`
```

Comment: sorry this is the first time I use this website = =

Comment: Poor spacing coz I don't know what to do with the tab thing

Comment: No worries, click "Edit" below your post and format the code properly using the `{}` button. There's a preview that will show you if it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bound method error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130574/bound-method-error)

Comment: just some missing parentheses. perimeter and Area are functions, you want to call them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a return value in the perimeter function:

```
def perimeter(self):
    return self.length*2 + self.width*2
```

Then call `A.perimeter()` instead of `A.perimeter`.

```
print "This is the perimeter: ", A.perimeter()
```

Likewise for Area.

```
def Area(self):
    return self.length*self.width


print "This is the area: ", A.Area()
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I rushed my answer and didn't bother checking it. Here is a working replacement for the `Rectangle` class and `PrintALL()` function. I also edited above.

It is better if you pass number types (not strings) to the function and you can avoid rounding errors by using floats instead of integers.

```
class Rectangle(TwoDShapes):
    def __init__(self, nameOfShape, length, width, numberofSides, numberOfVertices):
        self.nameOfShape = "Rectangle"
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.numberofSides = 4
        self.numberOfVertices = 4
        super(Rectangle,self).__init__()

    def perimeter(self):
        return self.length*2.0 + self.width*2.0
    def Area(self):
        return self.length*self.width

def PrintALL():

    A = Rectangle("Rectangle", 10.0, 20.0, 4.0, 4.0)

    print "This is the name of the shape: ", A.nameOfShape
    print "This is the length: ", A.length
    print "This is the width: ", A.width
    print "This is the number of side: ", A.numberofSides
    print "This is the number of vertice: ", A.numberOfVertices
    print "This is the perimeter: ", A.perimeter()
    print "This is the area: ", A.Area()
    print "\n"
PrintALL()
```

OUTPUT:

```
This is the name of the shape:  Rectangle
This is the length:  10.0
This is the width:  20.0
This is the number of side:  4
This is the number of vertice:  4
This is the perimeter:  60.0
This is the area:  200.0
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'length' is not defined

Comment: @LDs `self.length`, etc.

Comment: def perimeter(self):
        return self.length*2 + self.width*2
def Area(self):
        return  self.length*self.width
print "This is the perimeter: ", A.perimeter()
print "This is the area: ", A.Area() `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`

Comment: Ok I fixed it with putting int().         self.length = int(length)
        self.width = int(width)

Comment: Can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519118/attribute-error-for-python-2-7

Answer (score 1):

If the shapes won't change, they don't need to be functions:

```
class Rectangle(TwoDShapes):
    def __init__(self, nameOfShape, length, width, numberofSides, numberOfVertices):
        super(Rectangle,self).__init__()
        self.nameOfShape = "Rectangle"
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        self.numberofSides = 4
        self.numberOfVertices = 4
        self.perimeter = length*2 + width*2
        self.Area = length*width
```

Will work with the code you wrote. You don't need a function, as you can do the math for the `perimeter` and `Area` when it's initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but our teacher said we must include the functions (volume, area, surface area, perimeter, print All ) , and it's a requirement typed on the paper.

Comment: I guess they want functions because then if the length or width are modified the perimeter and Area values can be recalculated by calling their functions again.

Comment: @feedMe True. If you expect to be able to modify the shapes they should be functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from BasicClassShapes import*

###############################################

class Rectangle(TwoDShapes):
    def __init__(self, nameOfShape, length, width, numberofSides, numberOfVertices):
        self.nameOfShape = "Rectangle"
        self.length = int(length)
        self.width = int(width)
        self.numberofSides = 4
        self.numberOfVertices = 4
        super(Rectangle,self).__init__()

    def perimeter(self):
        return self.length*2 + self.width*2
    def Area(self):
        return  self.length*self.width

###########################################

def PrintALL():

    A = Rectangle("Rectangle", "10", "20", "4",  "4")

### Specs of Rectangle ###
    print "This is the name of the shape: ", A.nameOfShape
    print "This is the length: ", A.length
    print "This is the width: ", A.width
    print "This is the number of side: ", A.numberofSides
    print "This is the number of vertice: ", A.numberOfVertices
    print "This is the perimeter: ", A.perimeter()
    print "This is the area: ", A.Area()
    print "\n"
PrintALL()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class New:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


    def addition(self):
        return (self.a + self.b)

p = New(3,4)

print(p.a)
print(p.b)

print(p.addition())
```

Look at this code snippet, You need to call the function by using (), functions as p.addition() and variables as p.a