# why is the number_of_edges method in my graph not working?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have the following command:

```
print g.number_of_edges
```

and get the following output

```
<bound method Graph.number_of_edges of <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x00000000096512E8>>
```

what does this output mean?

Comment: if `number_of_edges` is a method then you should do `print g.number_of_edges()` to actually call the method. I usually encounter this output when I try to print the object itself rather then calling the object and printing its output.

Comment: [9. Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) from the Tutorial.  Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13130574/2823755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `g.number_of_edges` is a class method and there is no print method defined for the class, Python will simply print what is knows about the object (the class name and memory location where the object is stored).

Instead of `print g.number_of_edges` use `print g.number_of_edges()`. The difference is that `print g.number_of_edges()` calls the method `number_of_edges` and then prints its return value.