# What does "<bound method str.<native JS> of 's'>" mean?

Tags: python

(I'm using the website trinket.io because that is the only python website that isn't blocked at my school.)

I am trying to create a game with 2 different gamemodes. My code to get the gamemode is

```
gm = str(input("What gamemode do you want to play on? ([N]ormal or [S]udden Death)"))
gm = gm.lower
```

If I try to run `print(gm)`, it will print `<bound method str.<native JS> of 's'>` (Assuming you typed s in the input.)

Edit: All I had to do was add a () to the end of the gm.lower.

Comment: I think you meant to write `gm = gm.lower()` instead.

Comment: That was the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bound method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130574/bound-method-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to

```
gm = gm.lower()
```

`gm.lower` is the method itself not the resulting string of the `lower` method of the `str`

Comment: It was that easy?!? This is the answer but I can't add an answer this quick. I looked on Google and I thought every thing was unrelated. Now I know I made 1 simple, little mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @GiraffeMan3125 It's a simple solution but it teaches a good lesson